# Cloud Services, package upload speed

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

Why does the package upload speed differ so much between the various upload methods.

The methods I've used to deploy are

1. Within VS2013: Very slow uploads
2. Powershell Commandlets: Again very slow
3. Azure Portal: Blazingly fast

I would not complain if the speed differed by a few seconds or heck a minute or two, but I'm talking 10's of minutes for 45MB Deployment Package.

Method 1 & 2 takes over 45 minutes using high-speed broadband in New Zealand.
Uploading via method 3 takes just 30 seconds.

Something is not quite right.

Our network is not in question, I was able to simulate this from other networks too.

Comment: From our side (EU), the upload speed only depends on when we upload the package during the day. From VS it can vary from 5mn to 30mn (same speed observed from portal and VS)

Comment: We noticed this as well about a year or so ago. 
Have been doing direct uploads and manual deploys in the Azure portal ever since because it shaves around 15 minutes off the total time to deploy. We use Azure Storage Explorer to do the uploads - this is also super fast compared to VS2010. Hope MS fixes this sometime because frankly there's no excuse for having such a terribad upload as part of VS deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm the issue with deployment from Visual Studio taking much longer than direct upload of the package and as far as I know this is a [known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080445/why-does-azure-deployment-take-so-long) and [common](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483670/how-to-speed-up-azure-deployment-from-visual-studio-2010) issue since the very first version of Azure.

Nonetheless I would like to point out that upload via Azure Portal is a mere data transfer, after the package has been deployed it takes the service for some more time to become responsive, whereas after VS deployment the service is responsive immediately after the deployment is done. From this I conclude that the difference in deployment time might be due to provisioning of cloud architecture (creating, running or re-configuring of host OS VMs) for your cloud services.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander good answer, thanks for pointing out the other threads

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen of Azure publishing using Visual Studio vs the Azure Portal, there seems to be no significant difference except for the time it takes to upload the package. As the original poster stated, the Portal is extremely fast; whereas, Visual Studio takes forever to upload the package. I didn't realize the difference for a long time until I tried using the Portal one day just to see how that process worked and I was floored by the difference in speed.

I'd definitely recommend using the Portal vs Visual Studio. One caveat, you seem to need to use Visual Studio the first time around to create the Azure Tools certificate. Not sure if there's a way to create it without Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've seen why Visual Studio takes so long to do the upload.  If you start up Fiddler while the update is happening you'll see that Visual Studio is uploading the package in 65k blocks in sequence.  As you're in NZ you get our wonderful high latency to US servers, so sending lots of smallish requests is not optimal.

If you use a dedicated storage explorer they're usually much more clever and if the file you're uploading is large it will use larger blocks and also upload them in parallel.